# Как сделать функцию для приложения что бы можно было говорить в Android?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать функцию для приложения что бы можно было говорить? По сути что бы можно говорить как на Viber. Как её можно реализовать? В нете информацию я не нашёл. Безопасность можно опустить.

Comment: попробуйте поискать как TextToSpeech

Comment: Это по сути TextToSpeech  записывает аудиофайл, ну а потом его можно отправить иному человеку и вследствие получается  разговор или я не так понял?

Comment: извините я просо не понял вопроса, в viber там просто свой плеер, который записывает и воспроизводит файлы - здесь  TextToSpeech не при чем. Вот и всё, осталось научиться записывать звук используя диктофон, передавать аудио файлы, и накрутить плеер который воспроизведет это.

Comment: Это значить что нужно написать плеер для androida настолько который записывает информацию каждую секунду и передаёт её через сервера до иного пользователя?

Comment: client - server - client . Всё тоже самое что с обычным сообщением, только передается аудио файл, я не знаю как проще ещё написать)

Comment: Это лс автору. Что за вопросы ты пишешь? Ты думаешь так просто что взяло и начело говорить? Для твоей реализации надо 1.устроить запись звука и получать на выходе байты, для этого надо наладить работу с микшерами. 2.наладить сетевое общение, сокеты и тд. 3.прием на другой стороне от сокета ответ в форме байтов которые тебе прислали и оборот их в аудио поток.